# Log changes made in PS script

Tags: powershell

So i have a script which runs various changes in office 365 and has a menu with options that the admin would select an option and it would then perform the required task. What i wanted to do now was log all changes made and then update the file each time someone makes a change. Then on the next day it would create a new one and do the same. I can then create a clean up script for the folder location. Never really done this side of things so not to sure what is needed etc and the best way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: go to the Powershell Gallery site and search for `logging`. you will find many logging solutions. ///// if you actually are talking about self-modifying code ... that is a VERY complex thing that i aint about to try to do. [*grin*]

Comment: Thank you. I have a feeling this will require some modifying to get what i am ideally looking for. A quick look before seems to point that way. :)

Comment: you are welcome! [*grin*] glad to kinda-sorta help ... and i wish you good luck!